# Segmented control not changing index

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm coding a game, and I have a segmented control for the user to select a difficulty level. I've added some simple code inside the cases to check if the index changes, but it doesn't appear to. Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func chooseOnePlayerDifficulty(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch onePlayerGameType {
        case .sluggish:
            onePlayerGameType = typeOfGame.sluggish
            print("Sluggish difficulty selected.")
        case .average:
            onePlayerGameType = typeOfGame.average
            print("Average difficulty selected.")
        case .ninja:
            onePlayerGameType = typeOfGame.ninja
            print("Ninja difficulty selected.")
    }
}
```

Now, when I test this in the simulator, the only thing that prints to the console is "Average difficulty selected." No matter which one I select. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

EDIT: I've found an answer that works by asking this question on another forum. Thanks for the help though. Here's the answer from there that worked for me: [Here is the link to the answer](https://forums.swift.org/t/segmented-control-isnt-changing-to-the-selected-index/15642/6?u=thisisauzername)

Comment: Why do you expect the value of `onePlayerGameType` to change? No matter what value it has your code sets it to that same value. And none of your code depends on the segmented control.

Answer (score 2):

This part of your code sets `onePlayerGameType` to `.average`, when you select the control again the value is still `.average`.

```
 case .average:
        onePlayerGameType = typeOfGame.average
```

> I have a segmented control for the user to select a difficulty level

If that's all you need why do you need `switch` and not just assign it directly?

```
enum typeOfGame : Int {
     case sluggish
     case average
     case ninja
}

@IBAction func chooseOnePlayerDifficulty(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
                           // assuming  typeOfGame is enum
    let difficultyLevel =  typeOfGame(rawValue: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    onePlayerGameType = difficultyLEvel
}
```

Comment: But how would the compiler know which difficulty each index is?

Comment: @Uzair updated the answer. I don't know how your `typeOfGame ` looks lik. it'll help if you post the code in the question

Comment: I would set specific `Int` values to each `case` of your `enum` to ensure they get values that correspond to the index of the segmented control.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you registered action method with segment control in StoryBoard/XIB or in code

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "chooseOnePlayerDifficulty:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

Try with following

```
@IBAction func chooseOnePlayerDifficulty(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    let selectedSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    switch selectedSegment {
    case 0:
        onePlayerGameType = typeOfGame.sluggish
        print("Sluggish difficulty selected.")
    case 1:
        onePlayerGameType = typeOfGame.average
        print("Average difficulty selected.")
    case 2:
        onePlayerGameType = typeOfGame.ninja
        print("Ninja difficulty selected.")
    default:
        print("Assing default")
    }
}
```

**Edit** Right @JakeG, updated answer

Comment: Where would I put the action method in the code? I don't have a XIB file.

Comment: And when you created the `IBAction` through storyboard, if you selected `ValueChanged` as the event type, you won't need to add that line programatically.

Comment: Indexes start at 0, so my guess is you want .sluggish to start at case 0, not case 1 (and the rest all decremented by 1)